# Before uploading an xml file, html page should parse and show a summary of the xml file

Tags: html, servlets, jquery

I am using servlet and basic html to get an xml file and upload it via tomcat apache to a local server. But what I need is before actually submitting the form (xml file that I selected in 1 of the input file type tag) a pop up should come showing a summary of important items of the xml. This will make the user more confident, which file he/she is uploading. May somebody guide me in a direction?

I am using apache commons-file file upload API, jquery-ajax for popups and other effects, html for basic client and servlet for handling server side.

```
    `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");      


    DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory ();
    fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1*1024*1024);
    fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);

    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);

    try {
        /*
         * Parse the request
         */
        List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
             out.println(item.isInMemory());
            /*
             * Handle Form Fields.
             */
            if(item.isFormField()) {
                out.println("Field Name = "+item.getFieldName()+", Field Value = "+item.getString());

            } 
            if(item!=null){
                //Handle Uploaded files.
                out.println("Field Name = "+item.getFieldName()+
                    ", File Name = "+item.getName()+
                    ", Content type = "+item.getContentType()+
                    ", File Size = "+item.getSize());
                /*
                 * Write file to the ultimate location.
                 */
                out.println("Hello ");
                File file = new File(destinationDir,item.getName());
                item.write(file);
            }
            out.close();
        }
    }catch(FileUploadException ex) {
        log("Error encountered while parsing the request",ex);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        log("Error encountered while uploading file",ex);
    }`
```

> This is the html output I am getting, why is it not displaying the filename, content type and size. The file name is "test.txt" with "Hello" inside and is getting uploaded to my destination dir.
>   true
>   Field Name = confname, Field Value = 
>   Field Name = confname, File Name = null, Content type = null, File Size = 0
>   Hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this http://elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com/2007/03/asynchronous-upload-like-ajax-1.html
to make it work. Now I'm uploading the file in another temp location from servlet where I am parsing the xml to show summary of the xml file to be uploaded (again). In the summary page if the user finds everything correct then he/she can go with the upload or just come out of that popup and choose a diff xml file. Thanks every1 for their help :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, javascript will not open a file on disk like this. What you need to do is setup a service that will allow you to 'upload' the file to a temp space, then post back the contents to parse.

Then if the person decides to 'upload' the file or not, you'd be able to just move and rename the already uploaded file to the 'real' location.

Comment: @g19fanatic: This is the code, where i am using a temp location `DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory ();
fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1*1024*1024);   
fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);` So now how can I post back the contents to parse, can you please elaborate on it. Thanks for you time.

Comment: after the file has been temporarily uploaded to the tmpDir, using a jquery-ajax GET, using your servlet(?) open that file, read the contents and send them back to the client. jquery can then directly parse this xml data and display it anyway you would like. You could then have 'accept' or 'decline' buttons that would just do a post to either delete the temp file or move it to the actual path that you're interested in... To avoid someone just leaving after they upload the temp file, have something that will periodically sweep and empty the temp dir of old files

Comment: @g19fanatic: Can you show me an example or any link to do _using a jquery-ajax GET, using your servlet(?) open that file, read the contents and send them back to the client_ Sorry for the trouble I have recently started and facing problem.

Comment: ok... First php (for your servlet example...) using PHP's fopen and fread, read in the temporary file that was loaded http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php  this php 'form' should be retrieved using either jquery.get() or jquery.post() and using PHP's _GET/_POST variables for auth... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php 
  you'd then be able to parse the returned xml data (returned from your php servlet and available in ur function(data) from jquery) and do a jquery.parseXML to do what you want. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: this is all i can really give you without spending a LOT of time doing myself... which would not help you nor me at all... Its all there. You should be able to do it.

Comment: @Abhishek, if my answer does help you along the way, do not forget to mark it as the correct answer to help both of us with reputation on stackoverflow